# nginx & wordpress - config for permalinks doesn't work; downloads php-files instead

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, config

I've installed nginx and I try to run wordpress on it.
Everything works fine, except for permalinks.

Here is the vhost-file I'm using:

```
server {
listen 123456:80;
server_name my-domain.com;

if ($host ~* www\.(.*)) {
    set $wwwless $1;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://$wwwless$1 permanent;
}

root /var/www/my-folder;

index index.php;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

(I've replaced critical data in the above code with my-domain.com, my-folder and the ip 123456.)

index.php, the admin-panel and using the standard links (.../?p=123) work finde. If I enable some of the permalinks, index.php and the admin-panel still work. But if I try to open another site of the wordpress blog, my browser downloads the index.php :(

Comment: I could partially fix that by adding the following to location ~ .php$ {

fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;

Now I can access other sites of the blog. But if I try to access a blog post, like http://my-domain.com/1/hello-world/, I still get a download of the index.php. :/

Comment: A workaround for the last problem was using the build in permalinks and not a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for the .php location config:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include     /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my wordpress config modified to suit you.

```
server { # the redirecting from www to non-www
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri$is_args$query_string;
}

server {
  listen  80;
  server_name example.com;
  root /path/to/root;
  # make sure the directory /var/log/nginx exists
  access_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress_access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress_error.log;
  index index.php;
  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri$is_args$query_string;
  }
  location ~ \.php {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  }
  location ~ /\.ht { # avoid downloading htaccess, htpasswd, etc files
    deny all;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this vhost file

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name www.example.com example.com;
   root /var/www/www.example.com/web;
   if ($http_host != "www.example.com") {
             rewrite ^ http://www.example.com$request_uri permanent;
   }
   index index.php index.html;
   location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
   }
   location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
   }
   # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
   location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
   }
   location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   }
   # Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
   rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
   location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
   }
   location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   }
```

}